# What is the contraption that Aladdin gifts the Sultan?

Tags: plot-explanation, aladdin-2019

When Aladdin disguised as Prince Ali is introduced to the Sultan and Jasmine he brings a contraption covered under blanket and claims it is very expensive.

What is said contraption?

Comment: The Wheel of Fortune?

Comment: A screenshot of said "contraption" would be helpful.

Comment: No help from the novelisation. *Shifting on his feet, Prince Ali continued his presentation. Jasmine waited. He might not be acting like a prince, but he was one nevertheless, which meant sooner or later he was going to present her with some jewels or some over-the-top present to try to woo her and win her heart. Sure enough, as if on cue, **he pointed to one of the items now being offered. “I don’t know what that is,” he said, “but I bet it’s expensive.”** “And what do you hope to buy with this ‘expensive’ thing?” Jasmine asked. Behind her, she heard Dalia give a little snort.*